# For a 2nd order linear ODE,find the interval where some non-trivial solutions remain bounded and some become unbounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+(2\alpha-3)y'+\alpha(\alpha-3)y = 0$$

Determine all values of $\alpha$, if any, for which some non-trivial solutions remain bounded and some become unbounded as $t \rightarrow \infty$.

The general solution I got is

$$y(t) = C_1e^{(3-\alpha)t}+C_2e^{-at}$$

And I think the interval is $(-\infty,3]$, but this is not the correct answer. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you want one exponent positive and one negative so solve $0<3-\alpha$ and $-\alpha<0$     or  the other way  $0>3-\alpha$ and $-\alpha>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I answered this incorrectly previously. The solution is
$$
y\left(t\right)=C_{1}e^{\left(3-\alpha\right)t}+C_{2}e^{-\alpha t}.
$$
This solution is unbounded whenever
$$
\left(\left|C_{1}\right|>0\text{ and }\alpha<3\right)\textbf{ or } \left(\left|C_{2}\right|>0\text{ and }\alpha<0\right).
$$
On the other hand, the solution remains bounded whenever
$$
\left(\left|C_{1}\right|=0\text{ or }\alpha\geq3\right) \textbf{ and } \left(\left|C_{2}\right|=0\text{ or }\alpha\geq0\right).
$$
Assuming both $\left|C_{1}\right|,\left|C_{2}\right|>0$, the solution
is unbounded whenever
$$
\alpha<3
$$
while the solution remains bounded whenever
$$
\alpha\geq3.
$$
However, the wording was a bit "tricky." It asked for a region
where **some** solutions remain bounded and some do not. This
is clearly $\left(0,3\right)$. To see this, take $C_{1}=0$ and $\left|C_{2}\right|>0$
and vice versa.

Comment: the question asks "
Determine all values of $\alpha$, if any, for which some non-trivial solutions remain bounded and some become unbounded as $t \rightarrow \infty$." But it seems to me that your answer only considered the unbounded case.